# Sportsmanship vs Disciplined/Peer Pressure

Tags: discussion

Do these badges run against each other, at least for some time-frame?

It would seem to show sportsmanship, one would be encouraged *not* to clean up posts at all (whether bad -3 or good 3+).  Sometimes a question has 5 answers that say the same thing within one minute.  It could end up 3+ quickly while another better answer exists.  User duly upvotes other answers.  This badge would encourage users not to his own answer (at least within some time frame) until after the SMS badge has been earned.  After a while, user will forget about the question and never remove what is cruft on an aged question.

Sure, some people can gain the badge in 4 days, but not everyone is a fanatic.

BTW, anyone know if multiple upvotes on the same question counts as multiples or is it one per question?

Welcome your thoughts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a user is more concerned about  earning badges / rep than adding value through their posts, they are  unlikely to want to delete a post with 3 or more upvotes (that they would otherwise consider delete-worthy) *anyway* - you can only earn the "Disciplined" badge once, so there's no further 'benefit' to deleting >+3 posts. Consequently, I would think it's unlikely that the minor incentive of small progress towards another badge ("Sportsmanship") would  sway their decision one way or another.